# how to control guid url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, guid

My title is kadhal-rojave-roja-2  but the guid id is http://sample.com/kadhal-rojave-roja-2/. I need it without dashes, like this:

```
http://sample.com/kadhal rojave roja 2/
```

How to do it?

This is my post code:

```
  $new_post = array(
      'ID' => '',
      'post_author' => $user->ID, 

      'post_excerpt' => $excerpt,
      'post_title' => $post_title,
      'post_status' => 'publish',

    );
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Comment: As you can see by the way SO shows it, that's not an URL.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, a browser will encode the spaces as %20 instead even if you do find a way to do this. Google also recommends using underscores or hyphens instead of spaces and so it is much better for search engine optimisation.

Also a URL could be much longer if you use %20 as it is 3 characters rather than 1.